# Couchbase query does not see documents add recently

Tags: java, couchbase

I'm performing a test with CouchBase 4.0 and java sdk 2.2. I'm inserting 10 documents whose keys always start by "190".

After inserting these 10 documents I query them with:

```
cb.restore("190", cache);
Thread.sleep(100);
cb.restore("190", cache);
```

The query within the 'restore' method is:

```
Statement st = Select.select("meta(c).id, c.*").from(this.bucketName + " c").where(Expression.x("meta(c).id").like(Expression.s(callId + "_%")));
N1qlQueryResult result = bucket.query(st);
```

The first call to restore returns 0 documents:

```
Query 'SELECT meta(c).id, c.* FROM cache c WHERE meta(c).id LIKE "190_%"' --> Size = 0
```

The second call (100ms later) returns the 10 documents:

```
Query 'SELECT meta(c).id, c.* FROM cache c WHERE meta(c).id LIKE "190_%"' --> Size = 10
```

I tried adding PersistTo.MASTER in the 'insert' statement, but it neither works.

It seems that the 'insert' is not persisted immediately.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Joan.

Answer (score 4):

You're using N1QL to query the data - and N1QL is only eventually consistent (by default), so it only shows up after the indices are recalculated. This isn't related to whether or not the data is persisted (meaning: written from RAM to disc).

You can try to change the scan_consitency level from its default -  NOT_BOUNDED - to get consistent results, but that would take longer to return.

[read more here](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/architecture/querying-data-with-n1ql.html)

[java scan_consitency options](http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client-2.2.0/com/couchbase/client/java/query/consistency/ScanConsistency.html)